# Getting ALL First links in a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I know that using "a:first" will get the first link of a page. Lets assume we have the following:

```
<div class="masterclass">
   <a href="#">Link 1</a>
   <a href="#">Link 2</a>
</div>
<div class="masterclass">
   <a href="#">Link 1</a>
   <a href="#">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

Naturally I can use the following code to get the first "a" of the class "masterclass"

```
$('.masterclass a:first').click(function() {
alert('yayfirstlink');
});
```

However I do not understand how to get the first link of every "masterclass"

Comment: Yo _do_ get the first link of every masterclass with that piece of JS, don't you? `$('.masterclass a:first')` should contain an array with both first links in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) here because your selector will find all the anchor elements with in `.masterclass` then filter only the very first one. But when you use `.find()`, it will find all the `.masterclass` elements first then will find the first anchor element in each of them.

```
$('.masterclass').find('a:first').click(function() {
alert('yayfirstlink');
});
```

or if you are sure that the target element will be the first child of its parent then you can use [:first-child](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)

```
$('.masterclass a:first-child').click(function() {
alert('yayfirstlink');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var oFirstAnchor = $(".masterclass a:first-child");
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(".masterclass a:first-child")` is what you are looking for.

so:

```
$('.masterclass a:first-child').click(function() {
    alert('yayfirstlink');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how u loop through each of the masterclass and get the first link of it.
i don't know what you want to do with it though so i can only provide this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var fields = $('.masterclass a:first-child');
  $.each(fields, function(index, val){
     alert(index);
  });
});
```

this alerts the current links array index
http://jsfiddle.net/kBd82/6/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the first of type selector for this.

```
$('.masterclass a:first-of-type')
```

This way it will always select the first anchor tag in each `masterclass` div even if you put other things in the div later.

http://api.jquery.com/first-of-type-selector/